# ArgumentNullException was unhandled

Tags: c#

This is a part of a code that will saved image to database

```
Bitmap TempImage = new Bitmap(@cwd + "\\Final.jpg", true);
        pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(TempImage);//pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(imgName[0]);
        TempImage.Dispose();
        string name = textBox1.Text + ".jpg";
        MemoryStream mstr = new MemoryStream();
        pictureBox.Image.Save(mstr, pictureBox.Image.RawFormat);
        byte[] arrImage = mstr.GetBuffer();
```

then the program halts at `pictureBox.Image.Save(mstr, pictureBox.Image.RawFormat);` saying `ArgumentNullException was unhandled, Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: encoder`

what would be wrong?

Comment: `mstr` is null and hasn't been initialised

Comment: @user1016253 - yes it has - three lines from the bottom

Comment: Looks like somewhere within the implementation of Save, something needs a valid encoder, and you don't have one. Find out why.

Comment: Are you sure the first line is working properly?

Answer (score 4):

Going to take a WAG and say that *you shouldn't dispose of things you might be messing with later on*.

```
using( Bitmap TempImage = new Bitmap(@cwd + "\\Final.jpg", true))
{
    pictureBox.Image = TempImage // why do => new Bitmap(TempImage); here?
    string name = textBox1.Text + ".jpg";
    MemoryStream mstr = new MemoryStream();
    pictureBox.Image.Save(mstr, pictureBox.Image.RawFormat);
    byte[] arrImage = mstr.GetBuffer();    
}
// after this point, you'd better not be using pictureBox either!
```

Also, not sure why you are creating two Bitmaps... or using a "pictureBox" in order to save the image... Quite frankly, the more I look at this code the more I boggle.  Perhaps you should ask a question such as

> I am attempting to foo an image so that I may bar.  How do I do this?

and skip this bit of code altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of Save() will call FindEncoder() on the format you pass in as the second parameter (pictureBox.Image.RawFormat), and that is returning null.

Answer (score 0):

simply use

```
pictureBox1.Image =
        Bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg");
```